# Как вывести даные об итерации each

Tags: jquery

Как можно получить вот в этом коде номер итерации?

Пытался так:

```
$( "#sortable li" ).each(function () {
var num =0;
console.log(num);
num=num+1;
}
```

в консоле получаю такой ответ:

```
3  0
```

Не подскажите как правильно?

Comment: `$( "#sortable li" ).each(function (num) {
console.log(num);
});`  ....счет с нуля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Больше информации получите здесь https://api.jquery.com/each/
в функции доступны аргументы index и element (последнее можно заменить на this)

```js
$( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});

$( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( element ).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#sortable li" ).each(function (i, val) {

console.log(i+1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="sortable">
  <li>item-1</li>
  <li>item-2</li>
  <li>item-3</li>
  <li>item-4</li>
  <li>item-5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sortable li" ).each(function (i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```